# HTML5 and vertical-align? Fixed now?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I come from the  world, and have been looking at resources on google about doing multiple wrappers to vertically align content -- however it seems like it's really ugly.

Is there an easier way now with HTML5?  Is there some sort of implementation that uses something like the HBox/VBox mentality?  I saw there are examples for non-ie browsers -- is there a compliant way?

How the heck does anyone in their right mind do HTML now?  It's a mess!

//// EDIT

I've finally figured out how to vertically align an entire box over a screen, how I'm figuring out how to vertically center list items.

I've tried two methods to align this html:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#!/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#!/link1">Link #1</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

one using display:inline, the other using float:left (within a container).  When using inline, it seems the list items ignore the height: css, and when using float:, the links within the li do not vertically align.  Do I need to place div's within the li's to get them to vertically center as well?

Comment: Items that have `display: inline;` cannot have width. Use `display: inline-block;` for that. Also, did you mean "the other using `float:right`"? ...and by "the links within the li do not vertically align" do you mean "the links within the li do not vertically center"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why don't you try using `display: box` with `box-align:center`, this is CSS3, so not every browser supports it yet (only Chrome, FireFox, and Safari)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-align.asp

Comment: Flexbox is seriously new. The spec isn't even done yet (as of this writing). It's good to learn how to use it, but it's not useful in the wild. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @PatrikAlienus Well, he was specifically asking if HTML5 had a solution. I also mentioned that not every browser supports it. It really depends on what do you want to do, if you have people using old browsers you can't make use of most HMTL5 then. IMO, I wouldn't bother with making it IE compatible because thankfully IE10 is coming out, the only exception would be if your user base of oldie IE is quiet large.

Comment: HTML5 != CSS3. But sure, I guess HTML5 and CSS3 kinda go together, but they don't have to. Even though IE10 is out, history tells us that we have to support IE8 for a looong time due to immensely slow adoption time from IE users. And by the way; You **can** get quite a lot out of HTML5 for older browsers by using HTML5 shiv and Modernizr. I like the "puritan" way of doing things just as much as the next guy, but I know that without shiv and Modernizr the effectiveness of the site will drop and conversion will dwindle.

Comment: @PatrikAlienus It depends a lot on your user base, say... 10% are IE users, then you decide to stop supporting it (I hope this ends with IE10); else you could maybe charge a "tax" for using an old browser like a websites do http://www.kogan.com/au/blog/new-internet-explorer-7-tax/

Answer (score 4):

You can make the line-height property equal to the height of the LIs with display:inline-block for the LIs. When you do this the text will be in the middle of the line, the line being the same height of the LI, the text will be vertically in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 really doesn't have anything to do with element layout, such as vertically aligning content. As before, the markup is styled by CSS.

CSS is a totally different spec from HTML5, so no, nothing has changed.

---

If you're having trouble implementing a specific layout, then ask a specific question, and we can probably help out.

Comment: some people, and all the hype, refer to HTML5 to mean; HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript(1.8?). Any indication of this feature being available in CSS3?

Answer (score 1):

you can set an outer element to display:table and an inner element to display:table-cell. then, on the table-cell element, set vertical-align:middle; all its contents will be vertically centered.

It won't work on IE7 and earlier though, but hey, who cares??